# npm default dependency specificity

Tags: npm, dependency-management

In `package.json`, if I specify a dependency such as

```
"react": "~16.1.1"
```

This allows NPM to change the patch version only, i.e. it may use version 16.1.2, but it will not use version 16.2.X

Similarly, if I specify a dependency such as

```
"react": "^16.1.1"
```

This allows NPM to change the minor version only (the middle number).

But what if I don't have any character in front of the dependency version, e.g.

```
"react": "16.1.1"
```

Does this mean that only version 16.1.1 can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *"Pinning"* your projects dependency in `package.json`, (i.e. specifying a [semver](https://semver.org/) without a [caret](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) or [tilde](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1) range specifier), will result in a *"similar"* version being installed each time.

Given the example of; `"react": "16.1.1"` specified in your `package.json`, this will result in version `16.1.1` of `react` being installed each time `npm install` is run.

However, (notice that I put emphasis on the word *"similar"*), this does not mean to suggest that by *"pinning"* you will get all the *"exact same"* files that constituted to the `react` package version `16.1.1` when your packages were last installed. The reason for this is the `react` dependencies specified in its [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/package.json) utillize a combination of caret and tilde range specifiers. So the versions of those dependencies are subject to change. Likewise, the dependencies of those dependencies and so on, (aka: the dependency tree), are subject to change too.

Checkout [npm-shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) and/or [npm-package-locks](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) if you're wanting to truly lock down the dependency versions tree for publication purposes.